# Reading from multiple broker kafka with flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I want to read multiple kafka from flink.

I have a cluser of 3 computers for kafka. With the following topic

```
Topic:myTopic   PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2 Isr: 2
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
Topic: myTopic  Partition: 2    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
```

From Flink I execute the following code :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "x.x.x.x:9092,x.x.x.x:9092,x.x.x.x:9092");
properties.setProperty("group.id", "flink");

DataStream<T> stream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("myTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
stream.map(....)
env.execute()
```

I launch 3 times the same job.

If I execute this code with one broker it's work well but with 3 broke (on 3 different machine) only one partition is read.

[(In this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989443/flink-how-to-read-from-multiple-kafka-cluster-using-same-streamexecutionenviron) the solution proposed was

> to create separate instances of the FlinkKafkaConsumer for each cluster (that's what you are already doing), and then union the resulting streams

It's not working in my case.

So my questions are :

1. Do I missing something ?
2. If we had a new computer in the Kafka cluster do we need to change flink's code to add a consumer for the new borker ? Or can we handle this automatically at runtime ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've misunderstood the concept of Kafka's distributed streams.

Kafka topic consists of several partitions (3 in your case). Each consumer can consume one or more of these partitions. If you start 3 instances of your app with the same *group.id*, each consumer will indeed read data from just one broker – it tries to distribute the load evenly so it's one partition per consumer.

I recommend to read more about this topic, especially about the concept of *consumer groups* in [Kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation).

Anyway `FlinkKafkaConsumer09` can run in multiple parallel instances, each of which will pull data from one or more Kafka partitions. You don't need to worry about creating more instances of the consumer. One instance of consumer can pull records from all of the partitions.

I have no idea why you're starting the job 3 times instead of once with parallelism set to 3. That would solve your problem.

```java
DataStream<T> stream =
      env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("myTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
              .setParallelism(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I tried this and it's work but with this method I can't adapt my job to the number of partitions in Kafka. If I want to scale my application I have to stop the job and then relaunch it. What I wanted to do with my solution was to dynammically adapt the parallelism of flink to the number of partitions in kafka (ie. one partition = one job).
Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Flink indeed can't change level of parallelism during runtime. But changing number of partitions per topic in Kafka is also not automatic and you won't do it very often. I don't see the problem with restarting the Flink job with different parallelism setup.

Comment: In kafka we can [modify a topic at runtime](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#basic_ops_modify_topic) (the only constraint is '_adding partitions doesn't change the partitioning of existing data_'. In certain situation, I can think of different use case where we don't want to restart flink to scale the job and I try to find a way (if possible) to allow an uninterrupted service. But maybe it's not possible

Comment: I found what I was doing wrong, I forgot to fill the /etc/hosts :(
 Thanks for your help