# FlinkKafkaConsumer010 can not consume data with full parallelism

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a Kafka(0.10.2.0) cluster with 10 partitions(with 10 individual kafka server ports) on one machine which holded 1 topic named "test"

And have a Flink Cluster with 294 task slots on 7 machines, a Flink app with  parallelism 250 runs on this Flink Cluster using FlinkKafkaConsumer010 to consume data from Kafka Server with one group id "TestGroup".

But I found that there are only 2 flink ips with 171 tcp connection has been establised with kafka cluster, and more worse, only 10 connections are transfer data, only these 10 connections had data transfered from beginning to end.

I have checked this [Reading from multiple broker kafka with flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281564/reading-from-multiple-broker-kafka-with-flink), but not work in my case.

Appreciated for any information, thank you.

Comment: I've left some comments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044903/flink-on-yarn-parallel-source-with-kafka?noredirect=1#comment73307492_43044903, which should also be related to this question.