# Flink on Yarn, parallel source with Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I am trying to have parallelism with my Kafka source within my Flink job, but I failed so far.

I set 4 partitions to my Kafka producer :

```
$ ./bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper X.X.X.X:2181 --topic mytopic
Topic:mytopic   PartitionCount:4    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: mytopic  Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: mytopic  Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: mytopic  Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
    Topic: mytopic  Partition: 3    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0 Isr: 0
```

My scala code is as follow :

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
        env.setParallelism(4)
        env.getConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params)

    // **** Kafka CONNECTION ****
    val properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", params.get("server"));
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");


    // **** Get KAFKA source ****
   val stream: DataStream[String] = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[String](params.get("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), properties))
```

I run my job on YARN :

```
$ ./bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn 4 -yjm 8192 -ynm test -ys 1 -ytm 8192 myjar.jar --server X.X.X.X:9092 --topic mytopic
```

I tried a bunch of things, but my source is not parallelized :

[image: Kafka source on Flink WEB UI]

Having several Kafka partitions and at least as much slot / Task Managers should do it, right?

Comment: The FlinkKafkaConsumer should use 4 as its parallelism, and the partitions will automatically be evenly assigned to all parallel instances of the consumer. This seems a bit odd ..
Just to make sure: how is the produced data to the the topic routed to the partitions?

Comment: The data is produced by a script and sent to one kafka broker. Since my question I tried a bunch of things. I successed having parallelism by having 4 brokers and a topic with 4 partitions. 

Is the parallelism possible with just one broker and a topic with multiple partitions, or do we need multiple brokers as well ?

Comment: It should work for just one broker and 4 partitions. With a parallelism of 4, each consumer instance will be assigned 1 partition to read from.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. I am going to continue investigating !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I would suggest you to check two things.

1. When you are implementing the producer check if you are producing same key for each record flushed to Kafka. (you should have a well distributed key or simply set it to null).

`producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String,String>("topicName","yourKey","yourMessage")`

to

`producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String,String>("topicName",null,"yourMessage")`

2. Check if your Kafka producer library version is compatible with Kafka consumer library version.